# Reverse proxy for SSH/HTTPS on same port (443)

Tags: ssh, proxy, forwarding

I have an unusual problem. My home server environment has only one static IP. It has a web server that I would like to serve HTTP and HTTPS. However, most of the external networks I connect to it from block traffic over all ports except 80 and 443, thus preventing me from doing SSH over port 22. I can do SSH over 443, but that obviously conflicts with HTTPS requests.

My main question is if there is a way to set up a reverse proxy server that will forward domain.com:443 to my web server for HTTPS and allow me to redirect ssh.domain.com:443 to my web server internally on port 22 for SSH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible with the help of [sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml).

Comment: Looks promising, I will test it tonight. If it will let me handle multiple domains as well, I think we may have a winner.

Comment: It works! I can take it from here. Don't know why I had such a hard time finding that. Thanks a ton!